Non-Temporal / 'Explanatory' Causes
A long time ago, I encountered a discussion of two (or more) types of causes. One I remember well and have seen examined in various articles - the time-related causation where B happens after A and because of A. However, there was another one, which did not depend on time, where one may as well say 'X happens because of Y' even within a single infinitesimal slice of time (such as for emergent properties of objects based on more fundamental properties, or properties of larger composite objects because of the properties of their constituent parts), and now I'm having trouble finding what's the conventional way to refer to it. What is the latter called, and where can I read more about it?
Examples (which may be oversimplified, but would be:

A hydrogen atom is lighter than an iron atom because it consists of fewer (similar-mass) components.
In any given moment, a free-falling apple is experiencing acceleration towards the centre of the Earth (relative to it) because of the law of universal gravitation (because mass causes curvature of spacetime).

Neither of these causal relations have cause and effect placed on different points on the timeline. It seems like an elephant in the room in some scientific topics (and others), but I don't recall much being said about this kind of causation in discussions such as physical laws throughout life, and I'd like to get a glimpse of what I missed.

That’s just not a causal relation but more of a dependence or a constitutive relation. The phrase you may be looking for is metaphysical grounding. See the SEP article here:  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/grounding/. “Grounding is understood to be a form of constitutive (as opposed to causal or probabilistic) determination or explanation”

A common thread underlying causal reasoning is the consideration of counterfactual scenarios: A causes or grounds B if A had not been then neither would B

Was this in relation to an argument for the existence of God?

Judging by examples, what OP has in mind are causal and non-causal explanations rather than "non-temporal causes", see SEP, Non-causal and Mathematical Explanation. Namely, involving "factors that seem “mathematical”, that abstract from lower-level causal details, and/or that are related to the explanatory target via dependency relations that are (in some sense) non-empirical." "Non-temporal cause" is a very niche term used in theological contexts.

The description of metaphysical grounding seems to be in the right direction, though I also find it surprising because I don't think I've ever heard anyone say or seen write 'apples falling are grounded by Newton's laws' or the like.
